# Is it possible to specify at the site of a Property definition how many times to execute the Property?

Tags: scala, specs2, scalacheck

Such as this:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck { def is = s2"""
  MyThing should
    do something the right way $x1
                                """
    def x1 = prop(4 /*times*/) { (...) =>
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setParameters` and `minTestsOk`:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with ScalaCheck { def is = s2"""
  MyThing should
    do something the right way $x1
                                """
    def x1 = prop { (...) =>
      ...
    }.set(minTestsOk = 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Just `set(minTestsOk = 1)` should be enough.